# Problema na tentativa de conexão MongoDB via docker-compose com Robo3T. Como completar a conexão?

Tags: mongodb, docker

Desejo realizar uma conexão através do Robo3T de um banco de dados MongoDB que está sendo executado via docker-compose.

```
version: '3'

services:
  mongo-express:
    image: mongo-express
    container_name: mongo-express
    ports:
      - 8081:8081
    environment:
      ME_CONFIG_BASICAUTH_USERNAME: <usuario>
      ME_CONFIG_BASICAUTH_PASSWORD: <senha>
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_PORT: 27017
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME: root
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD: <senha>
    links:
      - mongo
    networks:
      - mongo-network

  mongo:
    image: mongo
    container_name: mongo
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: <usuario>
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: <senha>
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    volumes:
      - ./datadir:/data/db
    networks:
      - mongo-network

networks: 
    mongo-network:
      driver: bridge
```

[image: img-connection]

[image: img-connection]

Já tentei mudar os mecanismos de autenticação e as portas mas dá a mesma mensagem:

```
Cannot connect to the MongoDB at localhost:27017.

Error:
Authentication failed.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O seu docker-compose está correto. O problema está na conexão com a base de dados.

Conforme especificado no [Docker Hub](https://hub.docker.com/_/mongo):

> These variables, used in conjunction, create a new user and set that user's password. This user is created in the admin authentication database and given the role of root, which is a "superuser" role.

Ou seja, ao usar as variáveis de ambiente `MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME` e `MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD`, o usuário é criado como `root` na base de dados `admin`.

Sendo assim, é preciso especificar `admin` no campo `Database` da aba `Authentication`.